# Keeping image positioned overtop video as browser resizes

Tags: html, css, video

## Problem

I'm using Font Awesome to put an icon on top of a video. I want the icon to stay in that position in the left corner overtop the video even when the browser resizes and the location of the video player moves.

### index.html

```
<div class="videos">
    <div class="playContainer">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play play1 fa-2x"></i>
    </div><!-- /.playContainer -->
    <video src="assets/video/6025-4-normal-medium-yes.mov" class="beat" preload></video>

    <blockquote>
        <p class="quote">"This is really for my dad. I would love to go to his grave say, 'Dad you won, you got 'em.'"</p>

        <cite>
            <p class="name">Earl Lawrence</p>
            <p class="title">Son of Henry Lawrence</p>
        </cite>
    </blockquote>
</div><!-- /.videos -->
```

### video.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
VIDEO
----------------------------------*/

video {
    max-width: 900px;
    padding-top: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    opacity: 1;


    &:hover, &:active {
        @include transitions;
        cursor: pointer;
        // opacity: 1;
    }
}

.videos {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
}

.play1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5%;
    left: 6%;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Put the video in the same container(`.playContainer`) as the play button and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css to position the div playContainer where every you want.

```
.playContainer{
    background:green;  <-- you dont need, just used for reference
    position:absolute;
    left:0;  <-- where ever you want it
    top:0;   <-- ^^^
    height:10px;  <-- to make background appear
    width:10px;   <-- ^^
}
```

By giving the container element videos position relative, and give playContainer position absolute, you can position it anywhere you want and have it stay in the location based on the relative container size.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/0Lsaqdhf/)

Comment: Tried your fiddle, changing the left/top values to 50px/50px to get the square (which in this case represents the Font Awesome icon) overtop the video, then resizing the browser appears that the square is only on top of the video sometimes

Comment: notice that the square doesn't move at all? thats because its given an absolute position. The problem you are describing (i dont have a video so bare with me) is because the video itself is shrinking and changing size. If you make the video the same size as the main container and position it absolute with left 0 and top 0 with a width and height making it 100% it should work.

Comment: I'll try your new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Put your video inside a container div.

2) Put your text in a paragraph inside of that div, right after the video.

3) horizontally center your text with: `text-align:center`

4) vertically align your text using `margin-top:X%`

5) use the `position:relative` CSS property and the `top` `left` properties respectively to align your text over the video.

Comment: Trying to get the image positioned overtop the image, not the text.